# ¿Cómo centrar un elemento dentro de un menú, sin afectar otros elementos?

Tags: html, css

Bueno mi problema es algo pequeño, pero no logro resolverlo, he intentando centrar el `div` que contiene mi menú de opciones, pero al hacerlo, se desajusta el `div` que contiene las imágenes del lado derecho, he intentado con varios ejemplo que se encuentran aquí en SO, pero ninguno me soluciona el problema.

```css
/*Eliminamos los margenes y paddings que agrega el navegador por defecto*/
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

  /*Agregamos margenes inferiores a los parrafos*/
p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

body {
    font-family: Lekton;
}

header {
    background: #1f2721;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#logo a {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo a img {
    width: 40px;
}

#logo a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#nav {
    /*float: left; /* Desplazamos el nav hacia la izquierda */
    margin: 8px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden; /* Limpiamos errores de float */
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display: block; /* Convertimos los elementos a en elementos bloque para manipular el padding */
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#redes {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#redes a {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#redes a img {
    width: 40px;
}

#redes a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/local/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/local/fonts.css" />
  <link rel="Shorcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/ico/Icono.ico">

  <title> ¿? </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="">
          <img src="img/png/Logo.png" alt="¿?" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""> Inicio </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Contenidos </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> ¿Quién soy? </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="redes">
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/png/Git.png" alt="GitHub">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/png/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Así se está viendo el menú cuando intento centrar el `div` que contiene las opciones de navegación (Inicio | Contenido | ¿Quién soy?):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte, intenté utilizar float: left; en todos los div's pero al hacerlo no me deja centrar el `div` con las opciones de navegación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero de antemano hacer entender mi "problema".

PD: Solo estoy utilizando Html y Css. (Editado)

Comment: Trataste de utilizar la clase `col` de bootstrap?

Comment: Uh me faltó aclarar eso, no estoy utilizando Bootstrap, solo css.

Comment: porque no utilizas bootstrap? Alguna razón particular?

Comment: Quiero intentarlo sin utilizar ninguna herramienta externa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor que puedo hacer sin bootstrap es `display: inline-block; margin-left: 30%;`.  Se veria algo asi:

```css
/*Eliminamos los margenes y paddings que agrega el navegador por defecto*/
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

  /*Agregamos margenes inferiores a los parrafos*/
p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

body {
    font-family: Lekton;
}

header {
    background: #1f2721;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#logo a {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo a img {
    width: 40px;
}

#logo a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#nav {
    /*float: left; /* Desplazamos el nav hacia la izquierda */
    margin: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden; /* Limpiamos errores de float */
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display: block; /* Convertimos los elementos a en elementos bloque para manipular el padding */
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#redes {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#redes a {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#redes a img {
    width: 40px;
}

#redes a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/local/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/local/fonts.css" />
  <link rel="Shorcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/ico/Icono.ico">

  <title> ¿? </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="">
          <img src="img/png/Logo.png" alt="¿?" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""> Inicio </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Contenidos </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> ¿Quién soy? </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="redes">
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/png/Git.png" alt="GitHub">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/png/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con medias, o quieres decir medidas?

Answer (score 2):

para centrar fácilmente cualquier elemento se hace lo siguiente:

```css
#padre{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}
#hijo{
  position: absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
  <div id="hijo">
    yo soy el hijo
  </div>
  <div id="hermano">
    yo soy un hermano
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma mas elegante y de hecho, te hace un centrado perfecto, es usar `flexbox` que tambien es CSS puro.

modificas agregas estilos a la etiqueta `header` :

```
.header{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;

    /*  los demás estilos  */
}
```

Y te queda muchísimo mejor, incluso si quisieras darle un alineación distinta y todos los contenedores serán flexibles y responsivos.

> El contenedor `[div]` de las imágenes, se pasará a una linea siguiente, *sí y sólo si* el espacio horizontal se acaba.

Espero te sirva.

```css
/*Agregamos margenes inferiores a los parrafos*/
p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

body {
    font-family: Lekton;
}

header {

    /* Se hace el header flexible */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
    background: #1f2721;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#logo a {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo a img {
    width: 40px;
}

#logo a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#nav {
    /*float: left; /* Desplazamos el nav hacia la izquierda */
    margin: 8px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden; /* Limpiamos errores de float */
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display: block; /* Convertimos los elementos a en elementos bloque para manipular el padding */
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#redes {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#redes a {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#redes a img {
    width: 40px;
}

#redes a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="">
          <img src="img/png/Logo.png" alt="¿?" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""> Inicio </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Contenidos </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> ¿Quién soy? </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="redes">
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/png/Git.png" alt="GitHub">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/png/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
```